# Is it possible to convert a .mysql file to a .sql file?

Tags: mysql, dump

I am facing an issue with a MySql dump file (i.e `mydump.mysql`) generated by a Drupal export module. I am trying to import it on a local Drupal installation via Acquia Dev Desktop.

When browsing for my dump file, this application filters for `.sql`, `.sql.gz` and `.mysql` files. I thought it would load my `.mysql` easily, but I get an unsupported file type `.mysql` error.

Is there a way to convert my `.mysql` file into a `.sql` file, knowing that I don't have access to the original database used to generate my `mydump.mysql`? I would like to try to feed a `.sql` file to Acquia Dev Desktop instead.

**P.S.:** I am on Windows 7 if this is relevant. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just change the extension via Windows Explorer or command line, or copy the file giving the new copy the .sql extension? This doesn't sound like a conversion to me, just a rename.

Comment: Please copy the first 10 lines of `mydump.mysql` and paste it in your question.

Comment: @Aaron I tried a simple rename, but I when I try to load the file, I get a 'The Pipe is being closed' error message after a couple of seconds.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I tried to open the file with Notepad++, but it seems like the content is binary. When I try to paste the 10 first lines here, SO only displays one unreadable character.

Comment: Have you tried renaming .mysql file to .sql file?

Comment: You can also try a http://gist.github.com post

Answer (score 2):

For the records, I finally managed to load my dump into Acquia Dev Desktop after renaming the file to `.sql` and specifying/using exactly the same database name as the original database name.

I don't know what caused the original issue or what solved it, since I don't believe the database name should be an issue at all.